# Connecting to a Wifi Access point that requires web authentication through a captive portal

Tags: java, android, authentication, wifi

I'm trying to see if it's possible to log into a wifi access point (AP) that requires web authentication. I know that using .getScanResults() I can get security information from an access point with the .capabilities field of the scan result. But this value is left blank for an access point I am trying to connect to in which I know requires web authentication.

If I already know the credentials (ie: username/password), is it somehow possible to connect to this AP and then enter the credentials to use the wifi as normal?

I've found this question on this site, but it does not really answer this question.

[How to check WiFi is pass through web page login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577926/how-to-check-wifi-is-pass-through-web-page-login)

Any help is appreciate, some sample code is even better.

Thanks!

Comment: WEP auth or web-based auth like a captive portal?

Comment: Hey fvu, A web-based captive portal is what I'm thinking.

Comment: I read that link, and it does answer your question!  "Web authentication" happens outside WiFi, at the HTTP level, which is why the WiFi is not secured.  You have to programatically hit a URL and detect if it is getting redirected to a "landing page".  At this point it should be standard HTTP Forms Authentication, which you should be able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to automate web page operation is using HTMLUnit.

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

I used it with great success recently to log in and control a web-based KVM switch.

You can put it to a URL, tell it to fill out certain form fields and click certain buttons. In my experience it is very reliable.

Here's an example:

http://www.capybara.org/~dfraser/archives/378

I'm driving it from Groovy, but you can get the idea...

Comment: Thanks dfraser. I wasn't able to test it, as I've had to move on to a different project, but it looks like this would do exactly what I was looking for.