# How can I check if wifi network is protected with browser password check inside Android application?

Tags: android, password-protection, android-wifi

Is is possible to check if wifi network is protected with browser password check inside Android application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check WiFi is pass through web page login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577926/how-to-check-wifi-is-pass-through-web-page-login)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> Some Wi-Fi networks block Internet access until the user clicks through a sign-on page. Such sign-on pages are typically presented by using HTTP redirects. You can use getURL() to test if your connection has been unexpectedly redirected. This check is not valid until after the response headers have been received, which you can trigger by calling getHeaderFields() or getInputStream().