# Android designing an app to keep me logged into a wifi access point

Tags: android, wifi

At the gym where I work out, they have an open wifi access point. The way it is set up, once you "connect", you have to navigate to a web page (it is a 1.1.X.X ip address) and click the "I agree" button, after presumably reading the user agreement. The problem is, they have it set up to log you out once an hour, which always happens in the middle of my workout. I have the SSID remembered, so it connects automatically when I come in range, but I get an android notification that further action is needed to fully connect.

What I was wondering is if there a work around so that I don't have to click-through every hour? I was thinking of writing an app that could detect when I was in range, or when "half-connected", and then have it somehow complete the registration process. Perhaps this will have to be done by loading the web page in memory and then somehow clicking the "I agree" button.

What I would like help with is:

1) what is the terminology involved here? What state is the connection in when I am connected, but I haven't clicked through? What other connection states may apply? If I knew that, I might just be able to research this and come up with a solution. Are these different states "detectable"? It seems like it is since I get a notification that I need to complete the registration process when I am "half-connected".

2) I know there are plugins for desktop browsers that can click buttons (like the keepass plugins, which will log you into a site). How could I replicate this in Android? Ideally I would like to do it internally, in memory, rather than firing up a browser. Possible? Comments? Is my understanding and thought process sound here, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Get buff faster! Kidding... Next time you're on that page make sure you grab the html source of it. If you take a look at the POST data that clicking the button sends you likely could spoof sending that data yourself using a timer or maybe some smarts to detect if you're not fully connected to wifi. You could probably listen for wifi state changes in your app and then react accordingly.  [List of wifi states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_DISABLED)

I know Jsoup supports sending post data to a site using the data(key, value) method..

Ex.

```
Jsoup.connect("www.somewebsite.com").data("username", "dymmeh").get();
```

Again, this depends on how their setup is configured. It might not be able to be done through post data.

Another way would be to load the site via a WebView, find the "Agree" button, and click it via javascript..

Just some thoughts.. the implementation of all of this would be down to you.

Comment: That's a good start, and some great ideas. I'm going to leave the question as "unanswered" for a bit to see if any other ideas come in. I looked at the list of wifi states, and I didn't see anything that looked like the half-connected state. Do you have any more detail about that (such as what it is really called)? It's hard to search for it because I don't know what it is called.

Comment: After reading through the wifi states I don't think any of them would help. I found this which "might" be of some help - [How to check WiFi is pass through web page login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577926/how-to-check-wifi-is-pass-through-web-page-login)